# Right-align imageView of a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

How do I rightalign an imageview in a linearlayout - that is put the imageview to the right side of the linearlayout parent? android:layout_alignparent is not allowed in a LinearLayout. And I have tried with different gravity-constants.

This is a depiction of the screen and where I want to position the imageview. Its assumed that the parent is a linearlayout and orients its child in a horizontal order.

```
______________________
|                    |                  
|                    |
|                   X|
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |    
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|____________________|


<LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/dateImg"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:src="@drawable/unchecked"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use a relative layout instead ?

Or in case you must use a linear layout , add another view before the image view like this -

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/dateImg"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:src="@drawable/unchecked"/>
```

enter code here

Comment: thanks - I will leave LinearLayout for RelativeLayout

Answer (score 1):

Change orientation to "vertical":

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="#000000">

</ImageView>
```

Comment: This is correct answer if you don't want to deal with weights.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
 <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2">
         <ImageView 
             android:id="@+id/dateImg"
             android:layout_width="60dp"
             android:layout_height="64dp"
             android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
             android:alignParentRight="true"
             android:src="@drawable/unchecked"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout >
```

Comment: This would work as long as you remove the layout_weight parameter from the relative layout. You can put the height as wrap_content.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried
`android:gravity="right"`

Anyways in my opinion RelativeLayout is better for stuff like that :)